# How to install python easy_install with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, easy-install

Sorry if this is any easy question

I want to install easy_install for Python 3. Ive tried downloading ezsetup.py and running it but I get this

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ivan/Desktop/ez_setup.py", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/Ivan/Desktop/ez_setup.py", line 360, in main
    downloader_factory=options.downloader_factory)
  File "/Users/Ivan/Desktop/ez_setup.py", line 283, in download_setuptools
    log.warn("Downloading %s", url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/log.py", line 47, in warn
    self._log(WARN, msg, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/log.py", line 30, in _log
    if stream.errors == 'strict':
AttributeError: errors`
```

Next, I tried using wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py but I get this:

```
`wget: command not found`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `python3 ezsetup.py install`

Comment: Where do I copy the file? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Do you not have wget?
http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/22/install-wget-mac-os-x/

Comment: Please use python3.3. It is the current stable version